# How to display posts in blog page in 2 or 3 columns in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, posts

I am beginner in wordpress and I use the sparkling theme for my website.
I want to display my posts in blog page in 2 or 3 columns, but I don't know how. Currently, my blogs are displayed in a full width page layout.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show the HTML for that section of the page? Unless your theme has settings for that, sounds like you need some custom CSS.

Comment: How can I show the HTML for that section of the page? I'm sorry but I am a complete beginner. And another problem is that I don't know where to put custom CSS for my blog page.

Comment: If you open the page in your browser you can right click and choose inspect element to select the portion you are referring to.